# C# IUserStore implementation GetPasswordHash

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

By default, MVC 5 Single Page Application uses EntityFramework to store users and passwords for authentication.

In my scenario, I must use an existing homemade AuthenticationService.

I decided to create a custom IUserStore. I then must implement the `GetPasswordHashASync` to validate credentials.

Our architect considers this as a security breach but I do not agree with this. I then would like to get your opinion about this.

What is the difference between getting the PasswordHash for the database of another service on the same server node. In my opinion, I dont this it is a security breach...

Here's some code to demonstrate how it works.

The user logs in with his credentials so it calls the Login Method of my AccountController. Then, it calls the `UserManager FindUserAsync`:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

Since I create my own IUserStore, I call our service (WFC) like this:

```
 if (client.IsUsernameExists(userName, remoteInfo, out messages))
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = userName, Username = userName};
                }
```

Under the hood it then calls the `GetPasswordHashAsync`. My implementation then call our service again:

```
passwordHash = client.GetPasswordHash(user.Username, RemoteInfo, out messages);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface you are looking to implement is the IUserPasswordStore. Nothing wrong with that.

This is the correct way of implementing the IdentityStores of OWIN (and probably other authentication frameworks).

I've implemented my own UserStore for a MongoDB implementation of OWIN. Here is my implementation of the IUserPasswordStore

```
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
    }
```

The password hash is stored in the DB, so when you pull the user from the DB, it has a property which is the hash. So the appropriate implementation for GetPasswordHashAsync, is to return the hash from the user object.